# Most appropriate use of 'to prioritise'?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Online dictionaries I have consulted are ambiguous on this.  Does 'to prioritise' something mean **just** to give something a priority value (eg. Low) or to set that value to 'High' (or both)?

In many technical/project management fields, it is **important** to identify if a task's priority has been assessed.  Until then, it could be said to be in an 'un-prioritised' state (not 'de-prioritised', which implies that a previously set value of priority has been reduced).

If 'to prioritise' strictly means 'to assign a value of priority', then what is the term for **increasing** the level of priority.  Likewise, if the priority is un-set (not reduced), has it been 'un-prioritised' (as I referred to above), or maybe 'aprioritised'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online dictionaries are ambiguous because the word has both meanings.

In programmer-speak, "priority" refers to both a priority *value* (e.g. 0-100) as well as a priority *feature* (has priority [over X]). Thus, "to prioritise" is both to "assign priority value" as well as "give priority [over X]".

If clarity is of essence, I'd go for the explicit: **of unspecified priority**, **to specify priority**, **to increase priority**, **to decrease priority** all refer to the priority value with little to no ambiguity.